# Does specifying image size in CSS allow the browser to do layout before download is complete?

Tags: html, css, image

I've always tried to specify the height and width attributes for img tags in HTML. Not for style reasons, but because the browser then expects the size of the image and can do page layout even before the image has finished downloading. From the HTML spec:

> The height and width attributes give
>   user agents an idea of the size of an
>   image or object so that they may
>   reserve space for it and continue
>   rendering the document while waiting
>   for the image data.

I don't know why this has never occurred to me, but does specifying height and width in CSS, rather than inside the img tag, do the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

On (Almost) Strict mode: Yes, when the *<img>* `display` type is `block` or `inline-block`. Otherwise, if it's `inline`, FF3.5 will not preserve the space, but IE7, Safari3.2 and Opera9.5+ will preserve.(tested) 
On Quirks mode, FF3.5 *does* preserve the space like the others.

Prefer styling your document via CSS. [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) serves a different purpose:

> It provides a means to create
>   structured documents by denoting
>   structural semantics for text ...

Relevant links:

- [Images: height and width attributes](http://annevankesteren.nl/2004/01/images-height-and-width-attributes) @ annevankesteren.nl
- [Quirks mode and strict mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html) @ quirksmode.org

Comment: Are you saying you tested this, or quoting from the links? The first link you cite says the tags are deprecated, but they're actually not. The hspace, vspace, border, and align attributes are deprecated, but not height and width.

Comment: I tested this, literally. The citation is intended to clarify the purpose of HTML (semantic content markup) and CSS (apply style on elements). That's why the tags you mentioned are deprecated - you should apply them via CSS and not HTML.